# matplotlib: create PDF that does not combine image objects

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I like to use matplotlib to create a PDF and then I will often go in and tweak things with Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape.  Unfortunately, when matplotlib saves the figure as a PDF, it combines multiple images into a single object.

For example, the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = np.random.rand(10, 10) * 255.0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax.imshow(im, extent = [0,10,0,10])
ax.imshow(im, extent = [12,22,0,10])
ax.set_xlim(-2,24)
fig.savefig('images_get_combined.pdf')
```

creates the following PDF (after I manually converted to a PNG, so I could post it here)
[image]
When I open `images_get_combined.pdf` in Adobe Illustrator, both images are combined into a single image.  I cannot move one image relative to the other.

I tried to get around this problem using `BboxImage`, but as shown in this [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3918), `BboxImage` doesn't play nice with the PDF backend.  Perhaps the PDF backend with `BboxImage` bug will get resolved, but I wondered if there is another way to make the PDF backend save each image separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save as multiple pages PDF:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.random.rand(10, 10) * 255.0
with PdfPages('images_get_combined.pdf') as pdf:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
    ax.imshow(im, extent = [0,10,0,10])
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
    ax.imshow(im, extent = [12,22,0,10])
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

See also [Multipage PDF](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) example from the matplotlib doc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would rather avoid multiple page pdfs.  I typically lay out my figure how I want it in matplotlib, and then stick it in a report.  However, sometimes I come back weeks later and realize I want the images in different positions.  I don't want to have to recreate the pdf from scratch just to move something.

Comment: The official matpotlib FAQ also suggesting a way to save multiple plots to one PDF file as multipage only. I believe if you even make them subplots, you'll get a single image anyway.
http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file